# Why do I get a "???" error when I try to install Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit?

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to dual-boot Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit on my laptop, a [Toshiba Satellite C50D-B-120](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/laptops/satellite/c50-b/satellite-c50d-b-120/).

I have created a 241 GB partition. The other OS on the computer is Windows 8.1. The installation media was a DVD+R disk connected via USB drive. Secureboot and fast boot were disabled.

When I get to the installation page, I get this screen:

[Image in comment]

When I click continue, it loads for a few seconds and then this comes up:

[image]

When explaining what to do, please also explain why this occurs.

Comment: ill have to get back to this problem tommorow probally around 1/2 6 pm irish time

Comment: Just put the URL to your images in, rather than adding as an image.  That way we can just easily put the image in place (those of us with edit powers)

Comment: After getting this error, check /var/log/syslog for more details and add the last 20 lines or so to your question as a [code] block.

Comment: VTC as not reproducible because the OP has not signed on to this site since August, 2015.